# Erdos conjecture on arithmetic progression

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, arithmetic-progressions, arithmetic-combinatorics

My motivation for this enquiry is due to interest on Erdos conjecture on arithmetic progression.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Having come across this conjecture once again I decided I would give it a shot to at least try to understand what the conjecture states.

I have made a rough attempt to do so.

Could you please verify if my line of reasoning should be worked further or this approach is total nonsense?

Let **A** be a set of positive integers:$$\sum_{n\in A}\frac1n = \infty$$
Then **A** contains arbitrarily long Arithmetic Progressions (**AP**)

I state that $$\sum_{n}\frac1n\to \infty\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\frac1n$$
If *n* has upper bound:$$n\leqslant M, \sum\frac1{n}$$is a small set, thus converges.

$$\begin{align}
\text {Define function}: \ f(x)=\frac1x\space,(x \gt 0)\space \text{and} \space a_n=\frac1n,n\in A
\end{align}$$
[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klPF2.png)

Since intergral can be interpreted as area under the curve, it is clear that:
 $$\text S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k \geqslant \int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx$$

Also $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{1}^{n+1}f(x)dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\ln\lvert x\rvert\Big]_1^{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\ln(n+1)\to\infty$$
Thus
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\to\infty$$

Integral can be also written as left Riemann sum:
$$\int_1^nf(x)dx\approx \sum_{i=0}^kf(x_i)\Delta{x} \space{where}\space \Delta{x}=\frac{n-1}k\space and\space x_i=1+\Delta{x}(i)$$

For$$(n\geqslant2)$$$$\text{Let}\space\Delta{x}=1\space \Rightarrow \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}f(x_i)\Delta{x}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k$$
As $$\Delta{x}\to 0$$
$$\begin{align}
\int_1^nf(x)dx=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^kf(x_i)\Delta{x}\leqslant\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^kf(x_i)(1)
\end{align}$$

Since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^nf(x)dx\to\infty,\space\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big[\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^kf(x_i)(1)\Big]\space\text{must diverge too.}$$

$$\text{Notice that}\space x_i\space\text{forms arithmetic progressions}\space[x_i=x_0 + \Delta{x}(i)]\space and \space n\geqslant \frac1n.$$ 
Finally, integral can be thought as multiple addition of inverse **AP** terms times infinitesimal **del x**. Since integral diverges, airthmetic progression must diverge too, thus become arbitrarily long.

Comment: Hmm, how exactly does your integral argument relate to $\bf{A}$, the given set of positive integers satisfying $\sum_{n\in A} 1/n =\infty$?

Comment: Thank you for your time. Please take a look at Fig.1 again. If integral is interpreted as area under the curve it is clear that a_n term > integral from (n)--->(n+1). My argument is then summed in the last paragraph. Since the integral diverges, which is less then sum of 1/n (because del x can be made arbitrarily small in xi times the infinitesimal del x) the terms 1/n has to diverge too and since n >,= 1/n the AP itself diverges.

Comment: Integrating $1/x$ doesn't tell us anything on $A$. Overall, you can repair your post to show $\Bbb{Z}$ contains arbitrary long arithmetic progressions... Which isn't very interesting.